# Ext.ux.grid.CheckColumn -- fire event remotely

Tags: javascript, events, extjs

I have a Ext.grid.GridPanel which uses Ext.ux.grid.CheckColumn and Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander.

I have added a listener to RowExpander and I am trying to "check" the checkboxes created by Ext.ux.grid.CheckColumn after the row is expanded (with RowExpander). Any ideas on how I could do that?

My code below:

```
var expander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
    width: 15,
    selectRowOnExpand: true,
    align: 'left',
    tpl : new Ext.Template(
       ........
    ),
    listeners: {
        expand: function (row,record,body,rowIndex) { 
     ------>>>>>> what do I put here to fire an event into checkcolumn ?
         }
    }
  }
  var checkbox = new Ext.ux.grid.CheckColumn({
    header: 'Read',
    dataIndex: 'read',
    id: 'read',
    width: 30
  });

  var mygrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    renderTo: document.getElementById('inbox'),
    plugins: [new Ext.ux.IconMenu(), search, expander, checkbox],
    ..............
    ..............
    columns:[
       checkbox,
       { other column definition }
   etc etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: basically I need the checkboxes for each column to get into 'checked' status as soon as I open the rowexpander info

Answer (score 0):

The checked status is governed by the read field in the model, so you need to modify that:

```
expand: function(row, record) {
    record.set('read', true);
}
```